# How can I smooth out these signal traces using python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

The fast rise and exponential decay transients "spikes" you can see to the left in green represent neural activity that is changing over time.  in blue is a baseline reference signal.  both blue and green have some drift overtime as you can see.

Because I was experiencing baseline drift and a generally noisy signal, I tried to high pass filter.  I was able to high-pass filter them by inverse low-pass filtering them (see the brief tutorial [here](http://mpastell.com/2010/01/18/fir-with-scipy/)).  to the right is the filtered signal.

```
N=101
Fc=0.001  
Fs=1.14  # it's imaging data being acquired at just over 1Hz

h=scipy.signal.firwin(N, Fc, Fs/2)
h=-h
h[N/2] = h[N/2] + 1

#this is filter design output from the tutorial
#mfreqz(h)
#show()

y=scipy.signal.lfilter(h, 1.0, data)
yy=scipy.signal.lfilter(h, 1.0, data2)
```

It worked to get rid of the drift, although it introduced some artifacts, such as introducing a "fake peak" at the beginning, shrinking the original green peaks, and causing what looks like "undershoot" at the bottom of one of the green peaks.

I can probably tolerate some of these artifacts, but it is still too choppy for my liking.  Is there a way to smooth the noisiness here?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you want to low-pass filter (as opposed to high pass) if the goal is smoothing?

Comment: Not sure.  I'm actually a bit troubled by all the artifacts that filtering introduced.  Wondered if smoothing could be safer ... but yeah, will try low pass filtering now (or starting with a bandpass altogether)

Comment: I know that high-pass gets rid of baseline drift, and I remember someone back in the day telling me to avoid having to do it (maybe the artifacts are why).  I think low pass could be better.  I will try that alone, without the high pass, then both together.  hmmm.. The baseline drift here is caused by "photobleaching", and follows a linear decay. I bet if I could figure out the slope it would be straightforward to correct.

Comment: High pass will get rid of DC but if you want to smooth maybe then try a short MA filter, make sure you don't smooth away your signal of interest though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider first removing the undesired linear trend in the data by using

```
scipy.signal.detrend
```

The documentation is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html#scipy.signal.detrend).

You might also want to try subtracting a least squares fit to your baseline (blue) signal from your scientifically significant (green) signal.

Then, to smooth the data, consider a low pass filter, perhaps a moving average (MA) filter,or other type of low pass filter. You may have to experiment to define a filter that will remove the noise components, but not your signal of interest.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this tomorrow and update with my progress.

Comment: Of course anything you do to the signal will have some level of artifact. You really should be aware of the frequency response of the transformation that you apply to the signal to understand the nature of the artifacts. The spike you saw you can think of being produced by the filter that needs to settle on the input signal. Any filter will require a bit of this though a FIR filter typically more than an IIR. Consider throwing away the first part of the filtered response.  But really, you need to decide the frequency band that is important to the project and design the filter for that purpose.